# Dúvida sobre página JSP através de chamada

Tags: jsp, servlet

Se eu considerar que uma aplicação executou uma página JSP através da chamada 
[http://localhost:8080/aplicação/lista.processa](http://localhost:8080/aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o/lista.processa)
Qual das alternativas é a correta?

```
a - Pode existir um servlet acessando um compnente EJB.
b - lista.processa é o caminho de um componente EJB.
c - lista.processa é o nome dado ao mecanismo JNDI para o acesso a um EJB.
d - Não é possível executar a aplicação apenas com estas informações.
```

Comment: É uma questão de concurso ou afim? tem mais algum contexto?

Comment: é uma questão de curso técnico, é só isso mesmo.

Comment: alguém sabe responder?